# Can I navigate, zoom in and zoom out R plots?

Tags: r, mouse, plot, zooming, pan

I would like to know if R allows to pan and zoom images produced with the "plot" function. I would like to obtain the plot transformation using the mouse and not through the command line, is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's a bit old question but for future references, I've wrote a package doing precisely that (based on zoomplot {in pkg:TeachingDemos}). It's called zoom:

[The CRAN page on `zoom`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoom/)

And you are welcome to check the latest and greatest and expand the package on [Github](https://github.com/cbarbu/R-package-zoom)

Usage -

```
library(zoom) # Invoke the Library
# Call plot
zm()
```

The instructions for Usage in a normal plot is

***Mouse***:

- Scroll to zoom in and out
- Hold left mouse button to move

***Keyboard:***

- <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> (<kbd>h</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd>):           move left/right
- <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> (<kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>j</kbd>)   :              move up/down
- <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>i</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>o</kbd> :               zoom in/out
- <kbd>L</kbd>/<kbd>H</kbd>             : zoom in/out (x-axis only)
- <kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>J</kbd>             : zoom in/out (y-axis only)
- <kbd>p</kbd>               :             print to file
- <kbd>r</kbd>               :              reset limits
- <kbd>s</kbd>               :               show limits

<kbd>q</kbd> on the graphic window to quit

Comment: With hundreds (or perhaps thousands) of data points, the refresh felt slow in this library, and then R crashed. This is based on VERY limited  experience.

Answer (score 15):

Not with the default plotting device as its internal model is 'static'.

There are workarounds, tough: look for example at package [playwith](http://cran.r-project.org/package=playwith), or at a Java-based device such as the [iplots](http://www.rosuda.org/iplots/) package on Simon's [rforge](http://www.rforge.net).  There are also extensions like [ggobi](http://www.ggobi.org) and other on-going work (such as the Qt-based device which will in time replace ggobi) which try to make R-based graphing more dynamic.

But the main takeaway is: not, not really -- due to the way R graphics devices are designed.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Dirk's answer:  see also the [iWebPlots](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iWebPlots/index.html) and [RnavGraph](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RnavGraph/index.html) packages.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at Greg Snows zoomplot {in pkg:TeachingDemos}. You may be able to call that function with cursor interface using the tk toolkit. I think Greg's package also has examples of such an interface.

Answer (score 1):

To add to existing answers: I like to use the identify() function to manually add labels just to particular points I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add R graphs to [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/r/getting-started/) . This should be enough for the most common stuff.

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Now there are also http://www.htmlwidgets.org/ that add a great set of interactive visualizations capabilities to R. Most of them can easily be zoomed and panned.